# how to store a dictionary within a for loop

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, store

I want to store the values of data in a dictionary my dict{} but i got an error.

```
mydict= {}
for entity in entities:
     if entity.entity_id.startswith('sensor'):
         list = remote.get_state(api, entity.entity_id)
         data = {list.attributes['friendly_name'] : list.state}
         for key, val in data.items():
             mydict+= {key:val}
```

I got the following Error.

```
mydict+= {key:val}
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'dict' and 'dict'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Contrary to one may intuitively think, as the error indicates, `+=` operator is not supported for types `dict` & `dict`. Dictionaries are a little different than lists, and `+=` does not work like some sort of concatenation operator for them.

However, instead of using `+=` operator, why don't you try updating the inner for loop scope as done in the following snippet?

```
mydict= {}
for entity in entities:
    if entity.entity_id.startswith('sensor'):
        list = remote.get_state(api, entity.entity_id)
        data = {list.attributes['friendly_name'] : list.state}
        for key, val in data.items():
            mydict[key] = val
```

Alternatively, you can do a bulk update, as given below.

```
mydict= {}
for entity in entities:
    if entity.entity_id.startswith('sensor'):
        list = remote.get_state(api, entity.entity_id)
        data = {list.attributes['friendly_name'] : list.state}
        mydict.update(data)
```

Comment: you mean i have to change it inside key val for loop?  


   data = {list.attributes['friendly_name'] : list.state}
            for key, val in data.items():
             mydict[key]= val

Comment: I updated my code snippet to cover your entire code to avoid any misunderstanding.

Comment: it works. Thank you. I have an small question. How did you marked the code in comment as code. in the question i did it with ctrl+k. but it doesn't work in comment .

Comment: I usually just keep a blank line between the text and the code segment, and indent the code 4 space characters or a tab. There are people who use ` character to specify code blocks as well. You may want to read up on Markdown for further details.

Comment: If you believe your question is solved, remember to choose an answer to it.

Comment: Thank you.
test

    mydict= {}
    for entity in entities:
        if entity.entity_id.startswith('sensor'):
            list = remote.get_state(api, entity.entity_id)
            data = {list.attributes['friendly_name'] : list.state}
            mydict.update(data)

Comment: i tried right now "a blank line between the text and the code segment, and indent the code 4 space characters or a tab." but it doesn't work as you see in the test